# Dynamically created form submitting with preventDefault

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that lists a bunch of items with add to cart buttons, the user clicks the button it fires AJAX which adds the item to the php cart and adds the item to the sidebar for a visual cue of what's in the cart, with a remove button. Problem is, when i click the remove button it refreshes the page even though i have prevent default attached to the function

This works

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.additem').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('Added').attr('disabled' , true);
    $(this).closest('form.form_add').submit()

});

$('form.form_add').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "buy-page-handler.php",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: "json",    
  success: function(result) {
    var id = result.id;
    var name = result.name;
    var qty = result.qty;
    var price = result.price;
    $('#sidebar').append('<div class="cart_cont">'
                            +'<div class="desc">'+name+' '+price+'</div>'
                            +'<div class="remove">'
                                +'<form method="post" class="form_delete">'
                                    +'<button type="submit" class="removeitem">Remove</button>'
                                    +'<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+id+'">'
                                    +'<input type="hidden" name="item-remove" value="true">'
                                +'</form>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</div>');
      }
 });
});
```

This doesn't work

```
$('.removeitem').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.form_delete').submit()

});

$('.form_delete').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "buy-page-handler.php",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function() {
      alert("success")
      }
 });
});
```

This is my first attempt at using the jquery/ajax/php combination, so i'm sure its a bit rough.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `class="removeitem"` elements are added dynamically after the DOM is ready, so your new elements are not bound to `$('.removeitem').click()`. Try binding it by delegating to the parent -

```
$('#sidebar').on('click', '.removeitem', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.form_delete').submit()
});
```

Comment: It's just refreshing the page again, do i have to do something similar to function below it that runs the ajax?

Comment: Yes, try changing `$('.form_delete').submit(function(e) {` to `$('#sidebar').on('submit', '.form_delete', function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
<button type="submit" class="removeitem">Remove</button>
```

to:

```
<button type="button" class="removeitem">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, It doesn't refresh now but the submit function below is not firing, I'm getting nothing in the console and the alert isn't firing. Any ideas?

Comment: That because the form is not submitted now. If you are  changing button type from "submit" to "button" you have to change the handler event too. instead of "$('.form_delete').submit(function(e) {" use "$('.form_delete button').click(function(e) {".